# Laravel routes don't seem to work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, fedora

I'm new to Laravel.

I've set up a Fedora 23 server through Oracle VirtualBox, installed composer and created a Laravel 5.3 project as the html folder (for convenience, since it's accessible by just the virtual machine's IP address). I also disabled its firewall, since this is just for testing/learning.

I gave storage folder 755 permissions, and I get the welcome page showing on browser by just typing http://«IP».

I created a index.blade.php view, with the same code as welcome.blade.php but changing the word Laravel to "Something". Now comes the problem.

I've created a HomeController.php controller, so that I could get the php artisan route:cache without errors, since if I returned the view on routes/web.php file, it gave me an error:

```
[myuser@webserver]$ php artisan route:cache
Route cache cleared!

[LogicException]
Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.
```

So my files look like this:

routes/web.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This file is where you may define all of the routes that are handled
| by your application. Just tell Laravel the URIs it should respond
| to using a Closure or controller method. Build something great!
|
*/

/*
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('index');
});
*/

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getWelcomePage');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@homepage');
```

app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
        public function homepage(){
                return view('index');
        }

        public function getWelcomePage(){
                return view('welcome');
        }

}
```

public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (I removed the comment lines in the example here for length purposes)

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/public"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride none
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

After all this, I can see the welcome page by typing http://«IP», but if I type http://«IP»/home I only get a blank page. Browser tells me that the page returned with a 500 Internal Server Error, however at storage/logs/laravel.log nothing shows up (the last log was the error due to the php artisan route:cache not being able to execute due to the view being returned in the web.php file)

```
[2017-01-19 13:00:49] local.ERROR: exception 'LogicException' with message 'Unable to prepare
route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.'
in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:995
```

The weirdest part for me is that if I comment ALL the entries in the route file, I get a route not found exception for http://«IP»/home, but if I just type http://«IP» I still get the welcome blade.

I believe that my problem is something really simple, but after hours of searching and trial/error, I still can't solve this.

Any help/suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:** My problem is not the Closure error, I created controller methods for the routes. My problem is that the server only gives the welcome blade, all others give me an 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Do you have any route with Closure? Like `Route::get('my_route', function() {...});`?

Comment: I had them like this:
`Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('home', function () {
    return view('index');
});`
but it gave me the Closure error, so I created controller functions for them

Comment: That's odd. Try removing all the routes from your routes.php file and leave only this one: `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getWelcomePage');`. Even commented lines. Then run the cache command again and see if it works.

Comment: The cache command works with the lines commented out (I deleted them just to be sure anyways), my problem is that the server doesn't display anything else than the welcome page. If I type http://«IP»/home I get a 500 code, but laravel.log doesn't show anything.
Even if I delete all the Routes I still get the welcome blade (that's what's weirdest to me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it!

After reading comments on https://woohuiren.me/blog/installing-laravel-5-on-fedora/, an user that apparently had the same issue as me said the following:

> Seem issue this command solve the blank page (error code 500)
>
> $ cd laravel_project
>
> $ php artisan cache:clear
>
> $ chmod -R 777 storage
>
> $ composer dump-autoload
>
> I set SElinux to permissive, should be ok right?

I got the page showing with no problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Go ahead and accept your own answer so that other people who stumble across this issue know what helped :)

Comment: I can only accept it as answer tomorrow (StackExchange rules), but I'll do it :)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you can't use any route caching with Laravel 5, if you have any routes as closures (because it won't cache the function). A closure being like:

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Either stop caching your routes, or remove all of these closures. More information in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7319).

Comment: I did, if you check my routes/web.php file, you can see the closures are commented and I created controller functions to return the views:

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getWelcomePage');
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@homepage');`

Comment: I was under the assumption that another route with a closure may be hiding further down your file. If that's not the case, maybe try running a `php artisan route:clear` to reset things.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow as soon as I get back to work, but before leaving I did a route:list and both routes ('/' and 'home') displayed correctly, pointing to the correct controller and functions

Comment: Is there a chance that your webserver is looking at outdated cached routes? In other words, if you program in your home directory and then use a build tool to deploy to a different directory accessed by Apache (etc.), then your cache may still be out of date. You'll need to run `php artisan route:clear` in the directory that your webserver accesses. (It definitely sounds like, by reading all of the comments, you have two different directories and the one you are working on is fixed but the server is using old cache still.)

Comment: I doubt it, since I'm working a the "default" Apache directory (/var/www/html), but I'll look into it as soon as I get back to work tomorrow.

Comment: I ran `php artisan route:clear` (with no errors) and I can't still get my page running. Logs still don't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the error your log isn't the one that is causing the 500 error. If you delete that log and try to navigate to that route then you won't see any errors.  The last time I ran into this was my storage directories weren't created and/or the permissions on them weren't correct.  Make sure your storage directory is writable by the webserver (I usually set to 775) and all directories exist.  Create them if they don't:

```
storage/
|
|-- app/
|   |-- public/
|
|-- framework/
|   |-- cache/
|   |-- sessions/
|   |-- views/
| 
|-- logs/
```

Comment: I already gave the storage folder 775 permissions as I have read about it on another topic, and it didn't solve my problem, leading me to revert the permissions to 755. I think that the storage directory tree is all there, but I'll confirm it tomorrow as soon as I get back to work, and I'll give feedback on it.

Comment: I gave 775 permissions again, and checked the storage tree, it's all there, but it still doesn't show my page:

`[myuser@webserver html]$ tree storage/
storage/
├── app
│   └── public
├── framework
│   ├── cache
│   ├── sessions
│   │   └── ykUYX0zVingXqhM9DEOvQG9xbXWYNW6d53RuD4Ab
│   └── views
│       └── b18d705f49d4cb87cb2bde363b3ca5bd2bbb5823.php
└── logs
    └── laravel.log

7 directories, 3 files`

Comment: P.S.: I tried to edit the comment, but the 5 minutes had expired, sorry for the mess, wasn't aware that comments didn't support newlines.